# How to add extra style besides styles object for one element?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo, native-base

I saw one example few months ago where was added extra style to the same element like this:

```
<Button style={ styles.button && backgroundColor: '#222222'}> 
<Text> Learn more </Text>
</Button>
```

But can't remember how was the right syntax. It's not working now. How can this code be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have couple of options.

**Option 1:**

You can [spread the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and add the desired one after.

```
<Button style={{ ...styles.button, backgroundColor: '#222222'}}> 
  <Text> Learn more </Text>
</Button>
```

**Option 2:**

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to clone and add more properties to your object.

```
<Button style={Object.assign({}, styles.button, { backgroundColor: '#222222'})}> 
  <Text> Learn more </Text>
</Button>
```

**Option 3:**

[style prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style) can have an array of objects.

```
<Button style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: '#222222'}]}> 
  <Text> Learn more </Text>
</Button>
```

Comment: This should be the approved answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by passing an array of styles

```
<Button style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: 'white' }]} />
```